# Binding caps lock to escape in z-shell

Tags: zsh

I want to rebind the Caps Lock to escape in z-shell to make better use of the vi-mode in the z-shell line editor. I don't want to rebind it for the entire system. Is this possible?

(if that matters, I'm on debian)

Comment: I don't think so, as the system usually intercepts the scancode when capslock is configured as, well, capslock. I'll try to experiment later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, because this isn't done by the Z shell.

Raw keyboard make/break events come in from the keyboard device.  They are processed by a terminal emulator — either the one built into the operating system kernel or a GUI one such as `xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, `lxterminal` and so forth.  The terminal emulator translates the keyboard events into character sequences, and pushes them into the "master" side of a pseudo-terminal or the (usually hidden) "master" side of a virtual console.  These pass through the terminal line discipline, and *only then* does the Z shell see the result, as input read from the "slave" side of the pseudo-terminal/virtual console.

The "lock" and "modifier" keys aren't handled in the line discipline.  Think back to the days of *real* terminals (rather than "pseudo" and "virtual" termainals) connected over serial lines to understand this.  The characters that pass along the serial line from the terminal to the system have *already had* the modifiers applied.  <kbd>caps lock</kbd> plus <kbd>a</kbd> has already been translated into "A" by the terminal, and that's what is sent by the terminal and what arrives at the line discipline.  (Similarly, <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd> has already been translated by the terminal into the ASCII `ETX` character.)

So to adjust what <kbd>caps lock</kbd> — or indeed any other modifier — does, you have to *adjust the terminal*.  In your case, you have to adjust whatever terminal *emulator* you are using.

- With X Window System based terminal emulators, you can get fancy with X keyboard mappings, as there's a layer of X between the raw keyboard device and the terminal emulator program.
- With the terminal emulators built into operating systems, there's usually a quite different keyboard mapping system, involving an operating system keycode-to-character mapping layer in the operating system kernel, that you can play with.  It varies wildly from kernel to kernel (i.e. Linux to BSD), and what tools you run to adjust it vary wildly even from Linux distribution to Linux distribution (e.g. from `localectl` through `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` to `invoke-rc.d console-screen.sh`).

But because this changes the behaviour of *your terminal* it will affect every program that receives input from that terminal.  For a GUI terminal emulator, it will affect *every program* that you run that takes its input from that pseudo-terminal.  For the terminal emulator in the kernel that handles the virtual consoles, it will affect *every program* that takes its input from that virtual console.

It won't affect the entire system, but it will affect a great deal more than what you want, which is just to affect the Z shell.

### Further reading

- Andries Brouwer (2002-10-12).  "2. Keyboard generalities".  [*The Linux Keyboard and Console HOW-TO*](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.pdf).  version 2.13.  Linux Documentation Project.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation (sorry for not upvoting your answer ... I have not enough points yet)! I solved the problem by editing the /etc/default/keyboard file by adding the `XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape"` line.